# Update custom composer package fails if the packages require each other

Tags: php, git, tags, composer-php

I am working with multiple composer packages as a library and sometimes those packages require each other. For example, in `modolib/phpunit` I have:

```
"require": {
  "modolib/doctrine": "~1.2",
}
```

and in the package `modolib/doctrine` I have:

```
"require-dev": {
  // ...
  "modolib/phpunit": "~1.3"
},
```

To version the packages, I use tags. Calling `git tag` for `modolib/phpunit` in branch `master` puts out:

```
// ...
1.2.8
1.2.9
1.2.10
1.3.0
1.3.1
// ...
1.3.10
```

and `git tag` for `modolib/doctrine` at branch `master` puts out:

```
// ...
1.2.8
1.2.9
1.2.10
1.2.11
1.2.12
```

However, a `composer update` in `modolib/phpunit` will perfectly work, but an update in `modolib/doctrine` will throw this error:

```
Problem 1
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.9 requires moodlib/doctrine ~1.2 -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.8 requires moodlib/doctrine ~1.2 -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.7 requires moodlib/doctrine ~1.2 -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.5 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.4 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.3 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.2 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.10 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.*.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.1 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - modolib/phpunit 1.3.0 requires moodlib/doctrine 1.2.* -> no matching packages found
  - Installation request for modolib/phpunit ~1.3 -> satisfiable by modolib/phpunit[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.10, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9]
```

The current version of `modolib/doctrine` is `1.2.12` and no commits have been added since I created this tag except for the merge to master (I am using git flow).

Now it seems like the expression `"modolib/doctrine": "~1.2"` is correct, since I can update the packages in `modolib/phpunit` itself, but the composer has problems with noticing I am working in the package it is trying to request. Or could it have something to do with the difference between `require` and `require-dev`?

How can I solve this error and update my packages in `modolib/doctrine`?

**UPDATE:**

The reason why the update in `modolib/phpunit` worked is because `modolib/doctrine` requires `modolib/phpunit` in `require-dev`, but the composer does not load the `require-dev` sections of the packages it's loading during the update. Therefore, from the view of `modolib/phpunit` the packages do not require each other. Only `modolib/doctrine` is loaded, but it does not try to load `modolib/phpunit` while working in this repository.

Answer (score 0):

The composer does notice if the requirement is the package you are currently working in. What it does not notice is the tagged version. Of course Composer can not read your repository tags, so you need to provide them in the `composer.json`:

```
"name": "modolib/doctrine",
"version": "1.2.12",
// ...
"require-dev": {
  // ...
  "modolib/phpunit": "~1.3"
},
```

Now composer knows both name and version of your package and can validate the dependency.